# Kentico: How to send email on user account deactivation?

Tags: kentico

We are working on Kentico 10 (Portal Engine).
We can send emails on registration, forgot password etc.

Is it possible to send email to users if their account is deactivated from admin?

We can create a new email template but how to connect to deactivation?

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, this doesn't happen.  You can create a [global event handler](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/handling-global-events) for the User object and check to see if the user is enabled or not, then send an email based on a template for this.

Comment: Thanks Brenden, I will capture that in an event.